# Android Adding list item giving Error

Tags: android, listview

I have two lists I am adding the item from the `list1`, when clicked, to the other list but when I click an item. program is ending with out any errors
debug shows exception error
Following is the code :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String lst1[] = {"abdul","yousuf","khalid","john","egor"};
    String   lst2[]= {};
    Double  lp1[]={10.0,5.0,2.0,0.5,1.5};
    Double  lp12[]={};

    ListView lis1= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);
    ListView lis2= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst1);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst2);
    lis1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    lis2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    lis1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
         adapter2.add(item);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the code to see exactly which line of code is causing the issue?  and does Android Monitor show any errors?

Comment: Please post the LOGCAT while asking or post what kind of error or exception you are getting.Thanks

Comment: @PaulStringer i mentioned that in the post that i did run in the debug mode and it is showing exception error ,but hrer is no error in logcat  i apologize for not mentioning properly iam not an  android porgrammer but trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lst2);`
//  Internally a fixed size list will be generated ^^^^
```

then `lst2` array will be converted to a **fixed length** list which cannot accept new entries

```
public More ...ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
        init(context, resource, textViewResourceId, Arrays.asList(objects));
        //                                          fixed length array
    }
```

Read about [asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Solution :

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
              new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lst1));
             //  Pass array as new mutable list
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 =new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
              new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lst2));
```

Comment: I clicked the solution Accepted Tick   also the + points upvote is clicked but not recorded it is saying i need to have reputation of 15

Comment: i am glad that i could help and don't worry about anything here but make sure there can be lots of improvements as well in future with complexity, fetch data from your list not from `view` ,happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
lis1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String item =lst1[position];
         adapter2.add(item);

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much i tried ur suggestion but i was getting the same error again but   pavneet's solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

here is solution

```
 lis1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
         lst2.add(item);
         adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much i tried ur suggestion but i was getting the same error again but   pavneet's solution worked for me also  the two lines 'code`lst2.add(item);         adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();'`code` can be replaced with adapter.add(item) as mentioned by some other people

Comment: the error from the debugger this = {RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler@4447} t = {Thread@3973} "Thread[main,5,main]" e = {UnsupportedOperationException@4448} "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" message = {StringBuilder@4464} "FATAL EXCEPTION: main\n